# SoftLayer permissions required for relational properties

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Ruber's help, it has been determined this issue occurs when querying for relational properties using a [Legacy Object Mask](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Legacy-Object-Masks). This is unintended behavior and has been escalated within SoftLayer for fixing. The 'fix' Ruber suggested was to upgrade and use the [newer style](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-Masks) of Object Mask SoftLayer provides.

I am working to debug an issue encountered when querying the `billingItem`->`package` relational property using the SoftLayer SOAP API v3 `SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::getObject()` method over PHP. My gut is telling me that this is possibly related to API user permissions, as this code has worked in production since circa 2010 until ~2 months ago, whereas our API user permissions seem to change with some frequency.

Below is the snippet of code we use to query these relational properties, with some proprietary bits removed:

```
$client = getSoapClient("Hardware_Server");
$init = new stdClass();
$init->id = some_id_here;
$objectMask = new SoftLayer_ObjectMask();
$objectMask->operatingSystem->partitionTemplates->partitionTemplatePartition;
$objectMask->billingItem->package->items->prices->categories;
$objectMask->hardDrives;
$client->setObjectMask($objectMask);
$client->setInitParameters($init);
$data = $client->getObject();
```

If I inspect the request and response data, I can see the `billingItem` as well as `billingItem`->`package` objects being requested, however the `package` object is missing from the response. Trying to retrieve other seemingly sales-related items such as `billingItem`->`upgradeItems` returns an empty array as well.

My question to SoftLayer (or anyone who has encountered this before) is: Are there a certain set of permissions required to query relational properties such as `billingItem`->`package` or `billingItem`->`upgradeItems`? If so, what are they? Also, is there a list or diagram that answers *"If I wish to query x propery, I need y permissions"*?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any permission that can allow to get the relational properties such as **billingItem -> package** or **billingItem -> upgradeItems**

> You just need the "View Hardware Details" permission enabled and
>   access to the device

Anyway, Could you try this mask?

```
$objectMask->billingItem -> package;
$objectMask->billingItem -> upgradeItems;
```

Please let me know, if you're not able to get the package information, and if you are continue facing this issue, please could you provide more information, the exactly mask that you are using and what are you expecting. Also the server's identifier could be useful for further investigation.

There not exist a documentation available for permissions and their operations, but you can use the following method:

- [SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission/getAllObjects)

It will display all the available permissions, the names describe the operations that they allow

Comment: Hi Ruber - do you have access to the SoftLayer ticketing system? I'll open a ticket from our account to pass you the IDs and some further details if so. At this point, we suspect it's not permissions however we are not getting a 'package' object back for older servers on our account, newer servers do return this information however. Assuming you can view tickets in the SoftLayer portal, I'll provide all of the details :)

Comment: Yes, I have access to SoftLayer Ticketing System, you can provide the ticket's identifier and I will take a look of that

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The ticket identifier is 35435429

Comment: Great, I got it... I will take a look of that :)